# Code Editor for HTML CSS JavaScript with Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 3 textareas for each HTML, CSS, and JS.
Typing inside the CSS & HTML textarea for example:
`html { background: green; }`
will make the iframe green, you can then change green to blue without refreshing the page and the iframe turns blue. But when I write some JS code it executes only once. For example `document.write("1");` prints 1 inside the iframe but if I add another `document.write("2");` it leaves the iframe blank.

```js
// Executing code when clicking RUN

$("#runButton").click(function() {  // Adds the CSS code    
  // Adds the HTML code
  $("iframe")
    .contents()
    .find("html")
    .html('<style>' + $("#cssCode").val() + '</style>' + $("#htmlCode").val());

  // Placing the code from the containers into the iframe (BROWSER container) 

  // Evaluating JavaScript 
  document.getElementById("browserFrame")
    .contentWindow.eval($("#jsCode").val());

});
```

I expect new output inside the iframe to appear each time I add JS code just as it does with HTML & CSS. Please try it out here: https://online-code-editor.netlify.com/  (don't mind the disappearing icons)

Update:
I found that this

```js
document.getElementById("browserFrame").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

reloads my Iframe, but too quickly, Is there any way to make it work only when *RUN* is clicked? Or perhaps adding a certain delay?

Comment: If you call `document.write()` after the document has been closed, the document is cleared completely. That's just the way that API works.

Comment: What @Pointy said, you can witness this by inspecting it in web tools, the `document` is completely cleared and absent once you click run a consecutive time.

Comment: How do sites like codepen make it work?

Comment: They do things differently?  Probably reload an `<iframe>` completely on every change.

Comment: Code Editors don't simply inject changes into a document, they inject the markup each time there's a change or it's run. A.e. It doesn't simply try to inject `div { width: 100px }` *into* `<style></style>` within the iframe, it injects `<style> div { width: 100px } </style>` - they rebuild the markup structure with the code instead of assuming the markup will be available to be appended to within the iframe document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the iframe - use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
Here's an example - having a parent page with HTML, CSS, JS `textarea`s, and a sandboxed `iframe` for preview purpose:

[image]

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>App</title>
    <style>*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} iframe,textarea{width:100%;min-height:3em;}</style>
</head>
<body>

    <textarea id="html">Hello, stack &lt;b&gt;overflow!&lt;/b&gt;</textarea>
    <textarea id="css">body {background: #F48024;}</textarea>
    <textarea id="js">document.body.innerHTML = "&lt;b&gt;World!&lt;/b&gt;";</textarea><br>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals allow-forms" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <script>
        const textareas = document.querySelectorAll("#css, #html, #js");
        const iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe");
        const post = () => textareas.forEach(el => iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
            id: el.id,
            value: el.value
        }, '*')); // Use 'http://example.com' instead of '*'

        // Setup Events and Iframe Init
        textareas.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', post));
        iframe.addEventListener('load', post);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>

    <style id="__app__css"></style>
    <script id="__app__js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
            // if (evt.origin !== "http://example.com") return; // Fix and uncomment in production
            document.getElementById(`__app__${evt.data.id}`).innerHTML = evt.data.value;
            if (evt.data.id==='js') eval(evt.data.value);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="__app__html"></body>

</html>
```

The above is just a demo to get you started, and `eval`s as-you-type which might be dangerous while typing `for` loops or annoying trying to type `alert("something")` - You could improve the above by adding a checkbox *"Autorun"* and a button *"Run"* that becomes un`hidden` if autorun is unchecked.
Also make sure to use postMessage `origin` in production.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me a lot